# Setting up VAT in Magento CE 1.8.1

Tags: magento-1.8, tax, vat, tax-class

I set up a Magento store (UK Based) last year using Magento CE 1.8.1. The company wasn't VAT registered so I ignored VAT and how to implement it within Magento.

We are now registered for VAT, and so I decided to look into setting up VAT on the site.  I read a lot of articles and they all said go to `Admin > Sales > Tax` and set up customer classes, product classes and Tax Rule - oops I don't have a TAX section in `Admin > Sales`, on my version of Magento - Tax is in `System >Configuration > Sales` and it has NO options for setting up tax rules, tax amounts, product classes or customer classes.  I'm guessing here that I'm doing something badly wrong, but despite my efforts, I can't see what.

Can someone please help me? For heaven's sake, how hard can it be?

Comment: Sorry, that should read "on my version of Magento - Tax is in System>Configuration>Sales"

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that you are an actual admin user with permissions to see everything in Admin. Unless omeone has hard wired it so that the Tax menu in sales is absent then there is no other reason why you are not seeing it.

Check the user roles/permissions in the system menu.